# How can I get rid of VS2017 JavaScript error while debugging?

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I installed the latest release of Visual Studio 2017. It pops up a JavaScript error window when I start building an ASPNetCore project pointing at the following location:

```
"file:///C:/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Microsoft%20Visual%20Studio/2017/Enterprise/common7/ide/PrivateAssemblies/plugin.vs.js"
```

It appears irrespective of a type of a browser I choose to run my project on.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

OK. I don't know why, but when I upgraded IE9 to IE11 the issue has gone.